# Jenkins - Git repository configuration error

Tags: git, jenkins, git-checkout

```
D:\Work\Project>git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

This is the first command gets executed from Jenkins to pull the source code. I tried this command manually from command prompt as admin in windows 2012 Server R2 still the same result.
We use the following version.
git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0

Am I missing any additional configurations in Jenkins?

Comment: Seems that maybe your checkout configuration is wrong. Why are you set into the .git directory? Can you give more information about your configuration for the repo in Jenkins?

Comment: This problem is solved. I was looking in a different folder. It is working fine from Jenkins. From command prompt it is not working, which I am not bothered. We may close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> It is working fine from Jenkins. From command prompt it is not working,

Probable because:

- Jenkins does a proper clone of the repository, resulting in a workspace directory with a `.git` subfolder.
- `D:\Work\Project` is just a *copy* of the project, without `.git` subfolder, and is therefore not recognized as a Git repository in which you could run `git` commands.